# How to show UIElements hidden by keypad in iOS5?

Tags: ios5, uielement, keypad

In iOS 5 iPad supports 3 different keypads(normal, split, move-up). Previously when keypad appears controller will be notified though KeyboardDidShowNotification. Here, if we have any UI elemtns hidden by keypad will set an offset and push the elements upwards(by using scroll view). In iOS 5 we have to handle based on the type of the keypad. How do we know about the keypad type. What we can do for the new keypad-types?.

Thanks,
durai.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll automatically hidden textView or textField elements beneath keypad when click on edit text element, following code will help you for ios5:

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    _scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, _activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:_activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    _activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    _activeField = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you react on `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` or `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` you should be fine as they are only sent when the keyboard is shown in "normal mode".. if the user pulls it up or splits it, you will recieve a `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` (strange behaviour but apple's only choice to make it backwards compatible with iOS 4 apps)